# Kotlin Is there a way to flatten Map<K out T , List<V out T> to List<T>

Tags: kotlin

I would like to transform the Map to List

e.g I have

```
mapOf("a" to listOf(1,2),
      "b" to listOf(3,4)
)
```

I want the result to be

```
listOf("a", 1, 2, "b", 3, 4)
```

order must be Key and its Values, Key and its Values, ...

is there some function in kotlin that could help me with that?

Comment: there is no way that you ever get such a list out of that map. The reason is, that when you create the map this way you actually get a map containing: `"a"` with `2` and `"b"` with value `4`. Otherwise: yes... you can flatten it... maybe with something like: `mapOf(...).flatMap { (string, int) -> listOf(string, int) }` or similar... `map.flatMap { (string, ints) -> listOf(string).plus(ints) }`

Comment: @Roland sorry my bad, I updated question. Your `map.flatMap { (string, ints) -> listOf(string).plus(ints) }` works well for me. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My second comment variant as answer for a `Map<String, List<Int>>`:

```
mapOf("a" to listOf(1,2),
      "b" to listOf(3,4))
     .flatMap { (key, values) -> listOf(key) + values }
```

which gives a `List<Any>` with the keys followed by their values.

This example makes use of [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) and [`Map.flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html).

Comment: `map.flatMap { listOf(it.key) + it.value }`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: the answer below was written before the question was updated and changed how the map was created (see the history of the question for details). As the question now stands, the answer below will no longer work. It does work for the question as originally asked though, I believe.

@Roland is right that your map will never result in that list because there can only ever be a single value in the map against any given key. So I think you need to replace that map with a list of pairs.  You can then group it and flatmap it to get your desired result:

```
val pairs = listOf("a" to 1, "a" to 2, "b" to 3, "b" to 4)
val result = pairs
        .groupBy { it.first }
        .flatMap { (key, values) -> listOf(key).plus(values.map { it.second }) }
```

Another slightly different option which you might decide is more readable is this:

```
val result = pairs
        .groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
        .flatMap { (key, values) -> listOf(key).plus(values) }
```

Comment: This answer was added before the question was updated.  I'll add a comment on the answer to explain as you're right that, as the question now stands, the answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) over [`map.entries`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/entries.html#kotlin.collections.Map%24entries). Have a look at this [function](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/g2od0cbc3o3denc4inrihp384o/4kd0f4pv84s4gk0adjauv123bh):

```
val map = mapOf("a" to listOf(1,2), 
                "b" to listOf(3,4))
println(map)
val flattened : List<Any> = map.entries.flatMap {entry -> 
    //create list with key as only element, must be type <Any> to add other stuff later
    val list = mutableListOf<Any>(entry.key)
    //add values
    list.addAll(entry.value)
    list
}
println(flattened)
```

prints:

```
{a=[1, 2], b=[3, 4]}
[a, 1, 2, b, 3, 4]
```

@Rolands answer inspired this even simpler, more idiomatic version. It essentially does the same, but crams everything into one line:

```
 val flattened: List<Any> = map.flatMap {entry -> 
        listOf(entry.key) + entry.value
 }
```

Comment: Once you get used to functional programming it will be immediately clear what it does. I dont think it gets any simpler, if you want to preserve the order of the keys and values. In the link you also find a different version with `fold` maybe you like that one better ;)